# Heading won't even show in an HTML hangman game with embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this webpage won't even show the header in html.  I have the entire document listed here.  I am a beginner at javascript and html, but I thought I understood how functions work.  Apparently I do not. There appears to be a problem with the first "for" loop according to JSLint. Here is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hangman!</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <h1>Hangman!</h1>
</header>

  <script>

  var words = [
   "javascript",
   "monkey",
   "amazing",
   "pancake"
 ];

  var pickWord = function() {
    // Return a random word
    var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    return word;
  };

  var setupAnswerArray = function(word) {
    // Return the answer array
    var answerArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
    return answerArray;
   };
  };

  var showPlayerProgress = function (answerArray) {
    // Use alert to show the player their progress
    alert(answerArray.join(" "));
  };

  var getGuess = function() {
    // Use prompt to get a guess
    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing.");
    if (guess === null) {
    // Exit the game loop
    break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
    alert("Please enter a single letter.");
 };
};

  var updateGameState() = function (guess, word, answerArray) {
    // Update the answerArray and return a number showing how many times the          guess appears in the word
    // so remainingLetters can be updated
    guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing.");
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
    if (word[j] === guess) {
    answerArray[j] = guess;
    remainingLetters--;
   };
   };
  };

  var showAnswerAndCongratulatePlayer = function (answerArray) {
    // Use alert to show the answer and congratulate the player
    alert(answerArray.join(" "));
    alert("Good job! The answer was " + word);
  };

  var word = pickWord();
  var answerArray = setupAnswerArray(word);
  var remainingLetters = word.length;

 while (remainingLetters > 0) {
    showPlayerProgress(answerArray);
    var guess = getGuess();
    if (guess === null) {
      break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
      alert("Please enter a single letter.");
    } else {
      var correctGuess = updateGameState(guess, word, answerArray);
      remainingLetters -+ correctGuess;
    };
  };

  showAnswerAndCongratulatePlayer(answerArray);

  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You don't need a semicolon after an *if* block. *getGuess* doesn't have a return statement, so returns *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code. Change var `updateGameState() = function (guess, word, answerArray)...` to `var updateGameState = function (guess, word, answerArray)...`.

Change the `break;` in `var getGuess = function()` to `return;` as there is no loops.